# Livewire Data Binding Without Specifying Validation Rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Is there any way in Livewire to bind data without specifying validation rules? If a table has maybe like 20-30 fields, is there a way to bind the table data without writing validation rules for each field?

Comment: You don't need validation rules to bind data. If you want validation rules for each field without specifying them, you can use wildcards in your validation and ensure the `wire:model` uses the same syntax, such as `items.*.name` => `wire:model="items.{{$item->id}}.name"`

Comment: How can we avoid having a lot of fields inside protected $rules array? As per the doc, it is required to add the rules for existing Model instance. Otherwise the value does not display in the edit field.

Comment: Perhaps next time specify you're talking about Eloquent models? Anyhow, the docs state that you can easily bind an Eloquent collection using wildcard notation: 
`post.*.title`. So why don't you just do that?

Comment: Is there any way to bind the model without specifying all the field names?

Comment: If you have set the `$fillable` property, you can try the following in the mount (ENSURE `$rules` is `public`!): `$fillables = $item->getFillable(); foreach ($fillables as $fillable) { $this->rules[] = "item.*.{$fillable}"; }`

Comment: Again same as defining it in livewire. My question is to avoid writing all the fields in livewire like we usually do in controller, we pass the request->all() to the model create(). Is there anything like that? I don't think livewire allow such thing now as it needs to keep track of the properties. But still hoping if there is less verbose way of doing it.

Comment: No, not at all the same. Instead of manually setting them, you're letting the code do it for you. What "we" do with `request->all()`, that's bad practice. You should use form requests to validate your user's input, in which you also manually need to write up the fields. If it's so much effort to write a couple column names, don't bind to a model directly. Just use arrays keyed by the model ID and manually perform your updates.

Answer (score 0):

Albert!
As it is described [in the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/data-binding) to binding values you just need to add them to the component and then use the *wire:model* directive in the view and then the magic happens.

He's the example:

```
class MyNameIs extends Component
{
    public $name;
}
```

The view:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
 
    Hi! My name is {{ $name }}
</div>
```

Hope it help you!

Comment: Binding directly to the Eloquent Model on the edit field based on the id requires to add the protected $rules array for the fields we need to bind. How can we avoid that?